# CMake project building with SFML library

Tags: c++, cmake, sfml

i can't understand how to build SFML-project using `CMakeLists.txt` file.

Help me, please, if you have time. Thank you!)

### Details

I downloaded SFML library from official site (https://www.sfml-dev.org/index.php), moved it to my project root (see screenshots below), wrote C++-code using SFML and entered this `cmake`-command:

```
.../test_proj> cmake -G "Ninja" .
```

But in console output i got this:

```
CMake Warning at subdir_02/CMakeLists.txt:5 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindSFML.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "SFML", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "SFML" with any of
  the following names:

    SFMLConfig.cmake
    sfml-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "SFML" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "SFML_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "SFML"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.


-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/tim/Documents/c-c++/test_proj
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_executable(subdir_02 main.cpp)

set(SFML_STATIC_LIBRARIES TRUE)

find_package(SFML COMPONENTS window graphics system)

target_compile_features(subdir_02 PUBLIC cxx_std_17)
target_compile_definitions(subdir_02 PRIVATE SFML_STATIC)

target_link_libraries(subdir_02 ${SFML_LIBRARIES} ${SFML_DEPENDENCIES})
```

Here is the main C++-file using SFML (it is in project subfolder).

*.../test_proj/subdir_02/main.cpp*:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main() {
    sf::RenderWindow app(sf::VideoMode(800, 600, 32), "Hello World - SFML");

    return 0;
}
```

### Screenshots

[project root folder screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqiet.jpg)

[SFML folder screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7cAt.jpg)

[`main.cpp`-source folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWp9j.jpg)

Comment: Do exactly what the error tells you. CMake will not guess that you put SFML as a subdirectory of your project.

Comment: drescherjm, yes, you're absolutely right. But i don't know what i have to write in `FindSFML.cmake` file or somewhere else :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dumb rule when you have a `CMakeLists.txt` in which dependencies are discovered with `find_package()`: add their install folder to `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` while calling CMake configuration.

In you case, the CMake configuration of your project should be:

```
cmake -S . -B build_release -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="C:\Users\tim\Documents\c-c++\test_proj\SFML" -G "Ninja"
```

Indeed, SFML packages provide a CMake config file `SFMLConfig.cmake` in a subdir. It is a possible file `find_package(SFML)` is trying to find. CMake cannot know where this file is, so it looks into some specific subdirs under each path listed in `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`, and eventually some standard system paths.
Actually the search procedure can be very complex (https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html#config-mode-search-procedure), but for a native build `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` is your friend.

Comment: Ooo, yeee, thank you, SpacePotatoes! I'm gonna try it

Comment: I got new error related to wrong version of sfml:
```Could not find a configuration file for package "SFML" that is compatible with requested version "". The following configuration files were considered but not accepted: C:/Users/tim/Documents/c-c++/test_proj/SFML/lib/cmake/SFML/SFMLConfig.cmake, version: 2.5.1 (32bit)```

Comment: You were right, SpacePotatoes, with that variable `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`! It found SFML, but there appeared these new "version difficulties"

Comment: Did you download a SFML package built for the same OS/arch than the one you are targeting?

Comment: No, i didn't, SpacePotatoes. ok, im going to download another one!

Comment: Aaaaaaaa! Thank you, SpacePotatoes! You're the best! Everything worked out! :) I downloaded another SFML package for my system, added sfml libraries by hand:

`target_include_directories(subdir_02 PUBLIC "C:/Users/tim/Documents/c-c++/test_proj/SFML/include")`, 

`target_link_libraries(subdir_02 sfml-system sfml-window sfml-graphics ${SFML_DEPENDENCIES})`


AND IT WORKS!! Thank you guys!!! Thank You SpacePotatoes!) i'm overjoyed
Good luck to you :)